# How do I retrieve the name of the key column in a Cassandra keyspace/columnfamily using Hector?

Tags: java, json, cassandra, cql, hector

I want to convert a Cassandra keyspace/columnfamily row into a JSON string. My current code (fragments):

```
RangeSlicesQuery<K, N, V> rangeSlicesQuery = HFactory
    .createRangeSlicesQuery(this.keyspace, this.kSerializer, this.nSerializer, this.vSerializer)
    .setColumnFamily(this.columnFamily)
    .setRange(null, null, false, 100)
    .setRowCount(1000);

this.results = this.rangeSlicesQuery.execute();
this.resultRows = this.results.get();
this.resultRowsIterator = this.resultRows.iterator();

Row<K, N, V> row = this.resultRowsIterator.next();
```

From the row, I can get all column names/values easily (I am using the Jackson JSON API to create the JSON):

```
List<HColumn<N, V>> columns = row.getColumnSlice().getColumns();

for(HColumn<N, V> column : columns) {
    node.put(column.getName().toString(), column.getValue().toString());
}
System.out.println(node.toString());
```

My question is, how do I get the key column name? I know I can get the row's key value by doing:

```
row.getKey();
```

But I haven't found any way to get the key column's name for example, something like `row.getKeyColumnName()`. I've tried looking at KeySpaceDefinition, ColumnFamilyDefinition, ColumnDefinition, and ColumnFamilyTemplate. None of them seem to have this ability (though maybe there is a query that can be run against the template?)

Comment: Rows are identified by their keys and columns by their names. Perhaps you could clarify what you mean by "key column" name?

Comment: The name of the column containing the KEY values. For example, it could be "id" or it could be "UUID" - it is not present in the values of the HColumn generated by my commands.

Answer (score 1):

The row keys of Thrift column families do not have explicit names.

If you're using a CQL table, the columns that constitute your primary key have names, but Hector may not be a good fit for accessing them, as it was developed before CQL became the dominant way to model data. In either case, I would strongly recommend looking at the Datastax driver at https://github.com/datastax/java-driver if you're using Cassandra 1.2+.

Comment: Yeah, I have a working version with Datastax :). I was just hoping to keep it all in Hector since that is what the rest of my company/org uses.